# Make correct layout for TextView and ImageView

Tags: layout, textview, imageview

What Layouts need use for make this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<div id="itemWrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="png">
            <img src="xxx.png">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="png">
            <img src="xxx.png">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="png">
            <img src="xxx.png">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="png">
            <img src="xxx.png">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            text text text text text text text text text text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item{clear:both;}
.item .png{float:left;height:50px}
.item .text{float:left;height:50px}
h1{text-align:center}
```